# Display a Hashmap json from REST API, as a table in Angular 5

Tags: java, json, angular

I have a REST API returning a Hashmap `<String,<String,Integer>>`. I need to use this Hashmap Json to display a table in Angular 5. I have tried the following till now, but the table is still empty. I am not very sure how to access the nested object in the model class properly in the HTML File. Where am I going wrong?

This is the **frequency-table.model.ts** file where I have defined the structure of the HashMap.

```
export interface FrequencyTable {
obj: {
    key: String;
    val: {
        key_in: String;
        val_in: Number;
    };
} 
}
```

This is the HTML File

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Thread Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Query</th>
            <th class="text-center">Frequency</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let post of _postsArray">
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 15px;">{{post.key}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 15px;">{{post.val.key_in}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 200px;">{{post.val.val_in}}</td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is the **frequency-table.component.ts** file

```
export class FrequencyTableComponent implements OnInit {
  _postsArray: FrequencyTable[];

 constructor(private tableService: TableService) { }
 getPosts(): any {
  this.tableService.getPosts()
    .subscribe(
        resultArray => this._postsArray = resultArray,
        error => console.log("Error :: " + error)
    )
 }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
```

This is the **service.ts** file

```
@Injectable()
export class TableService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
getPosts(): Observable<FrequencyTable[]> {
return this.http
    .get('\getQueryCount')
    .map((response: Response) => {
        return <FrequencyTable[]>response.json();
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
   }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
  }
  }
```

This is the REST API returning Hashmap json:

```
@RestController
public class QueryCounterController{

@Autowired
ReadFileService rfservice;


@GetMapping("/getQueryCount")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object>  getQueryCount() throws IOException{

String filename = "file.txt";

return (rfservice.readFile(filename));}
```

}

**Sample Json:**

```js
 {
     "key1": {
     "xyz": 3,
     "abc": 2
     },
     "key-2": {
     "pqr": 3,
     "uvw": 2
     }
  }
```

Comment: One of things that may go wrong is in `var obj = this.getPosts();` - this line of code returns immediately without waiting for the http request to complete. You should move your logic inside `subscribe` function.

Comment: I removed the code for ngOnInit(). It still doesn't work

Comment: @apoorva96, your response conversion in angular app is invalid. You are not sending list of objects as a response. You are sending map means only one object. So, convert your response to list of objects as you like in service.ts

Comment: @swarooppallapothu could you explain it with some code please

Comment: @apoorva96, you can do in 2 ways. #1. change return type in java as List<Object> instead of Map<String, Object>. #2. convert your response in service.ts as list of objects like FrequencyTable

Comment: @swarooppallapothu I changed the return type in java as List<Object> and kept everything else same. Its still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by making the following changes:

**frequency-table.component.ts**

```
export class FrequencyTableComponent implements OnInit {
_postsArray: Array<any> = [];
 constructor(private tableService: TableService) { }

 ngOnInit() {

  this.tableService.getPosts().subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
   Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    var obj1 = data[key];
    console.log('key is ' + key);
     Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key1 => {
      console.log('key inner is ' + key1 + ' val is ' + obj1[key1]);
      this._postsArray.push({k: key, l: key1, m: obj1[key1]});
    })
  });
  console.log('array is ' + this._postsArray.toString());

   });
  }
```

**frequency-table.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class TableService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
getPosts(): any {
return this.http.get('/getQueryCount');
}
```

**frequency-table.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Thread Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Query</th>
            <th class="text-center">Frequency</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let post of _postsArray">
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 15px;">{{post.k}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 15px;">{{post.l}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 200px;">{{post.m}}</td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have removed **frequency-service.model.ts** class for the time being. Now I am getting the table as desired. Thanks @SEY_91 for your help.

Answer (score 0):

getPosts is returning an Observable of map:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getPosts().subscribe(obj => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        this._postsArray.push({obj: {key: key, val : { key_in:obj[key].key, val_in :obj[key].val}}});
      });
    });
  }
```

Html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let post of _postsArray">
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 15px;">{{post.obj.key}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 15px;">{{post.obj.val.key_in}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 200px;">{{post.obj.val.val_in}}</td>

        </tr>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be obj.key in the last line?

Comment: you mean {obj: {key: key, val : obj[key] } }  ??

Comment: add  the structure of the json response maybe I could figure out the problem

Comment: how should I access this in HTML now?

Comment: I tried to parse the response the same way you did it in ngOnInit before editing the question, otherwise I have no idea how the json response structure is

Comment: Json Response structure is present at the end of my question